# How do I statically retrieve current LAT & LNG for instagram location?

Tags: java, google-maps, latitude-longitude, android-maps-v2, instagram-api

```
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String PARAM_NAME_CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
private final int COUNT = 100;
private static final String instagramAPI = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?";
private static LatLng mLatLng;
private static final String LAT = "lat=";
private static final String LNG = "&lng=";
private static final String distance = "&distance=";
static Location location;
GoogleMap map;
private Context context;
static double latitude;
static double longitude;
public  InstagramPhotosClient(double latitude, double longitude) {


}


LocationManager service = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location1 = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

public static String getRequestCacheKey() {
    return String.valueOf(latitude) + String.valueOf(longitude);
}
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void getPopularPhotos(AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {
    String url = instagramAPI + LAT + latitude + LNG
            + longitude;
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put(PARAM_NAME_CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_ID);
    client.get(url, params, handler);
}
```

}

I have to statically reference the url in another class using the loopj http jsonhttpresponsehandler, however I don't think I can statically find my current location using google maps lat and lng.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up the LocationManager after you declare it, and before you get the longitude and latitude from getLastKnownLocation. This is how I would approach it:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {}
});
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
```

Comment: See, that's what I thought would work but I get the message "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getLastKnownLocation(String) from the type LocationManager" I cannot use loopj without making a static reference. So, instead of completely redoing my code I'd like to just fix these few lines somehow by creating a static reference. I'm not sure how to thought.

Comment: Ummm I think you should create your location manager during the onCreate, and pass the reference to this class.